# How can I hover and trasition on boxes at the same time? only use css and html

Tags: html, css, hover, transform, transition

I have a problem I can not solve.

The goal is for hovering the mouse over the yellow square in the top left to trigger each of the colored boxes below to expand to reveal the content of the p tags within in addition to the h3 tags they contain. Hovering over the yellow square should also trigger the yellow square to rotate 180 degrees.

I have tried the CSS below, which doesn't work as intended.

```
.rotate-arrow {
    text-align: center;
}
.rotate-arrow .button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 22px 980px 30px 0;
    transition: transform 0.6s linear;
}
.rotate-arrow img:hover ~ .container .colored-boxes .box{
    /* transform: rotate(180deg); */
    max-height: 250px;
}

.colored-boxes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.green-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #007B2D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* .box:hover {
    max-height: 250px;
} */
.blue-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #004F91;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.red-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #950000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.colored-boxes h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 16px 0px 26px 16px;
    margin: 0;
}
.colored-boxes p {
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 32px 15px;
}

 <div class="container">
    <div class="rotate-arrow">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="colored-boxes">
            <div class="green-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 1</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 2</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a r</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="blue-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 4</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a rcontentIt is a long established fact that a </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 5</h3> 
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="red-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 7</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 8</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3vuf0xp/

Comment: please check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution:

```
.rotate-arrow:hover ~ .colored-boxes .box {
    max-height: 250px;
}

.rotate-arrow:hover .button {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Note that this triggers the behavior when the .rotate-arrow div is hovered over, rather than when the yellow .button div inside .rotate-arrow is hovered over. This is because currently [there is no parent selector in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), so we can't select the yellow box's parent element's sibling elements using pure CSS. The :has() pseudo selector, which would also let us achieve what you want in pure CSS by letting us select .rotate-arrow when it contains a hovered .button (the selector would be `.rotate-arrow:has(.button:hover) ~ .colored-boxes .box`), is a [Level 4 selector that currently cannot be used in stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), only with JavaScript functions like `document.querySelector()`, and is not supported by browsers yet.

If you would like the behavior to trigger only when the yellow box is hovered over, rather than the yellow box's parent element which includes the empty space to the right of the yellow box, you can either:

1. use JavaScript to respond to hovering over the yellow box
2. if you really do need a pure CSS solution, the best you can do (that I can think of) is make the parent element of the yellow box match the width of the yellow box by transferring the margins you have on `.rotate-arrow .button` to `.rotate-arrow` like so (aside: do you really need that huge right margin?)

   ```
   .rotate-arrow {
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 22px 980px 30px 0;
   }

   .rotate-arrow .button {
       margin: 0;
   }
   ```

Here's a working snippet:

```css
.rotate-arrow {
    text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 22px 980px 30px 0;
}

.rotate-arrow:hover ~ .colored-boxes .box {
 max-height: 250px;
}

.rotate-arrow:hover .button {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-arrow .button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition: transform 0.6s linear;
}


.colored-boxes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.green-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #007B2D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blue-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #004F91;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.red-boxes div {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #950000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 27px 30px 27px;
    transition: max-height 2s linear;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.colored-boxes h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 16px 0px 26px 16px;
    margin: 0;
}
.colored-boxes p {
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 32px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="rotate-arrow">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="colored-boxes">
            <div class="green-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 1</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 2</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a r</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="blue-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 4</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a rcontentIt is a long established fact that a </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 5</h3> 
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="red-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 7</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable contentIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Box Title 8</h3>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I understand you to be looking for a solution which will enable the following behavior: hovering over the yellow box in the upper left (div .button) causes that yellow box to rotate 180 degrees, and all of the colored boxes below to expand in height to reveal the `<p>` text under the "Box Title" `<h3>`s.

It is a little hard to be sure that the above is what you are looking for because of the grammar issues in your question, so if you are looking for something else please edit your question appropriately as clearly as you can, and I'll try to come back and edit my answer accordingly.